# How does linux resolve wildcard locahost subdomains (e.g. : `ping test.localhost`) when `test.localhost` does not exist in /etc/hosts or dns server?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, subdomain, localhost, hosts

For example in ubuntu 20.04 LTS where the `/etc/hosts` file is empty:

```
>>> cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

`ping` still works for any subdomain of localhost:

```
>>> ping test.localhost
PING test.localhost(ip6-localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
^C
--- test.localhost ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1028ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.049/0.053/0.058/0.004 ms
```

or:

```
>>> ping test2.localhost
PING test2.localhost(ip6-localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
^C
--- test2.localhost ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.042/0.052/0.063/0.010 ms
```

This [answer alludes that the system resolver is involved](https://superuser.com/a/781633/537036) but how does it actually happen?

If `localhost` in `/etc/hosts` is replaced with another value the subdomains no longer work:

```
>>> cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       testname


>>> ping testname
PING testname (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from testname (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from testname (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
^C
--- testname ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1011ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.071/0.075/0.080/0.004 ms

>>> ping new.testname
ping: new.testname: Name or service not known
```

Why does it work for localhost and no other hostname and how is it achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux systems, the resolution is governed by `/etc/nsswitch.conf` that defines, for hostnames and other things, which sources of data to consult.

A typical configuration has:

```
hosts: files dns myhostname
```

If you remove `myhostname`, your test does not work:
(I have to remove `dns` as well because my local recursive nameserver has a zone for `localhost` and hence replies)

```
# grep hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts: files
# getent hosts foobar42.localhost

(no output)

# grep hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts: files dns myhostname
# getent hosts foobar42.localhost
::1 localhost
```

This also shows that you don't need `ping` and in fact `ping` is almost always the wrong tool to use to troubleshoot. `getent` is the user facing tool to check resolution of anything defined in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
(and as bonus, `getent` favors IPv6 over IPv4 with the usual `/etc/gai.conf` setup, but you can force IPv4 with `getent ahostsv4 ...`

The `myhostname` "plugin" is documented at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-myhostname.html

It says:

> The precise hostnames resolved by this module are:
>
> [..]
>
> - The hostnames "localhost" and "localhost.localdomain" (as well as any hostname ending in ".localhost" or ".localhost.localdomain") are resolved to the IP addresses 127.0.0.1 and ::1.

Mystery solved :-)
(and the content of `/etc/hosts` is in fact irrelevant here)